# PHP - header does not carry over previous parts of current url

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $hash = $_GET['hash'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    //method 1
        //echo "<script>document.location.href=resetpass.php?email=".$email."&hash=".$hash"</script>";
    //method 2
        header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/resetpass.php?email=".$email."&hash=".$hash");
        exit;
}
```

Why does anything i try to do not work in this case? The hash and email is inside the URL at first but as soon as i change the URL it does not carry over. I don't understand this because it should be able to grab it and store the variable before the URL is created. Is there some kind of reason as to why? I've already looked on stack exchange for answers on this but I am not seeing any answers for this question specifically.

This is the form initialization maybe it's a problem here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
<form action="resetpass.php" id="#form" method="post" name="#form">
```

Comment: var_dump and see if both are set/not empty and enable error reporting.

Comment: you also need a previous GET to fetch those arrays.

Comment: Your malformed string with an extra trailing double quote should trigger a syntax error.

Comment: why do i always get down votes? this was a good question with good answers? am i missing something here? I get no errors and there is another field "$password" i carry over that does work but it's a post not a get. @funk forty you can also see the get right above header.

Comment: You should post your entire form. Btw, this `id="#form"` and `name="#form"`; there shouldn't be `#` signs here and those suggest that you might be using javascript. If you get empty values, then that means that there is something not being passed somewhere. @user2455808

Comment: well should i just post the entire script? i am really still learning and know about 80% of php. i have it like that because it was a suggestion from another site to get the post information into the URL. i don't understand why it's so difficult to do something that should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/resetpass.php?email=$email&hash=$hash");
    exit;
```

It's working tested.

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this

```
 header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/resetpass.php?email='$email'&hash='$hash'");
```

Comment: You don't need the single quotes here.  Your values will end up including them.